# Installing PCL 1.7 (trunk) on ROS Groovy

Tags: pcl, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i tried do install the current PCL trunk for the last 2 day without success. I know that there are some solutions to do this in this forum and elsewhere, but no one works for me.

I have to say that i'm quiet new to ROS und PCL and also not a Linux expert. So i can build the PCL trunk and PCL_ROS, but it doesn't exist as ROS package then.

I need this for a university project, it would be great if somebody could help me out there and discribe how to get it run in simple words. Thanks!

Greets Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66238/installing-pcl-1.7-(trunk)-on-ros-groovy/) by [manox](https://answers.ros.org/users/5277/manox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-06-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) on 2013-06-29**:
Did you follow the description at http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl17 ? If so, can you give any error messages or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

clone https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl.git in your catkin workspace.

Then use catkin_make_isolated.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2013-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on 2013-09-11**:
I followed your instructions but it gives such error during cmake(after cloning pcl17-trunk):

CMake Error at cmake/pcl_targets.cmake:103 (add_library):
Cannot find source file:

```
include/pcl/ModelCoefficients.h
```

Any suggestions?

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-09-24**:
this might help http://answers.ros.org/question/44821/updating-to-pcl-17-in-ros-fuerte/

**Comment by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on 2013-11-27**:
Thanks @ctguell, finally I got it working under Hydro(where pcl17 were pre-provided)